# Correlation between different types of variables

Tags: r, sas, regression, correlation

I am running a logistic regression on a data set containing Continuous, Ordinal, Categorical and Dichotomic variables.

I would like to know how to calculate the correlation for all possible combinations (see matrix below - cases marked with an X do not occur in my data set) in order to check for colinearity. I can do this either with SAS or R.

---

```
             Continuous    Ordinal    Categorical     Dichotomic
Continuous        X           1             2              3
Ordinal                       5             6              7
Categorical                                 8              9
Dichotomic                                                 X
```

Case 8 I use `proc freq data=data chisq ;` to return Cramer's V.

As for the rest I am unsure - is it possible for cases 3, 7 and 9 to consider a dichotomic variable as categorical in two classes in order to compute Cramer's V?

Comment: @SabDeM won't work if there are factors.

Comment: The question is pretty explicit about having ordinal and categorical data. One pair of variables OP "marked with an X do not occur in my data set" is continuous-continous. The only thing `cor` would work on OP doesn't have.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V) suggests `cramersV` from the `lsr` package in R.

Comment: Dichotomous variables can be seen as either categorical or ordinal variables with two categories or levels, so **9** is a special case of **8**, **7** is a special case of **5** and any solution for **1** or **2** can be applied to **3**